# How to make vscode recognize c++ headers

Tags: c++, linux, qt, eigen

(I use Zorin OS 17 Core which is based on Ubuntu and Debian)I'm new to c++ and linux and I've been trying to use the SFML, Qt and OpenGL libraries for days but the vscode keeps giving errors like: `#include errors detected. Please update your includePath. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit (/home/golissson/Documents/Programação/C++/Qt/untitled/main.cpp).C/C++(1696)` and: `Include file not found in browse.path.` This is really discouraging, I would be very grateful if you could help.

I've tried downloading them via the package manager, tar.xz files and I've also changed the includePath of the c_cpp_properties.json folder.

Comment: First of all get the code to actually compile (in the terminal, forget VSC for now) and run. THEN configure VSC to get rid of the incorrect red squiggles. Also I believe this error message has a link to the manual, explaining how to fix it. Don't download any archives manually for now, everything you need should be in the package manager.

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-linux

Comment: Use cmake. Use Qt Creator to create a project for you, if you have trouble creating a working CMakelists.txt. If you are using the packges from your Linux distro, make sure you have the dev packages for the relevant  libraries installed, and use `dpkg` to see if the files are really installed, and where.

Comment: @BoP thanks a lot bro, i feel like an idiot having problems with something so simple lol